# What does MULT on UK standard visitor visa mean?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, multiple-entry, terminology

I applied for a six month single entry standard visitor visa, but the visa I got says Number of Entries: "MULT". Does this mean they gave me a multiple entry visa even though I applied for a single entry visa? Can I make multiple short term visits within the 6-month period over which my visa is valid?

Comment: AFAIK the standard UK visitor visa allows multiple entry, unless it is endorsed as single entry. The MULT means multiple entry.

Comment: I was sure this would be a duplicate, but it seems not to be.  There are questions about UK "MULT" visas, but they all have to do with something else.  None of those questions is as simple as "what does 'MULT' mean?"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The UK does not issue single entry visitor visas except in (very) unusual circumstances.

Your visa allows multiple entries during its validity period, as stated on the visa vignette https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/854601/visa-vignettes-used-for-certain-categories-of-UK-visas-Dec-19.pdf

So yes, you can make multiple short term visits, providing each time you enter you can satisfy the Border Officer, if asked, that you continue to meet the visitor eligibility criteria, in particular V4.1 to 4.3 of the Rules https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor